# May I know where to buy this adapter and do i need to install a driver to use it?

Tags: drivers, conversion, rs232

May I know where to buy this adapter and do i need to install a driver to use it?

I tried to reply to that post but i'm not allowed to : (

[image: serial adapter]

*Referenced post* - [Using an Rj45 to D9 RS232 Adaptor with a laptop to control an RS232 device](https://superuser.com/questions/1373841/using-an-rj45-to-d9-rs232-adaptor-with-a-laptop-to-control-an-rs232-device)

Comment: Just checking for the driver question – exactly what are you going to be using it with?

Answer (score 1):

The adapter in your picture is a 8P8C socket to D-subminiature DE-09M adapter. It is mostly obsolete now but you might be able to obtain one from any normal electronics distributor such as Mouser, Digikey, Farnell, etc.

You don't need a driver to use it *IF* you are using it to connect two RS232 (or two RS422) devices with DE-09F connectors using a short length of 8P8C terminated cable like those often sold as "RJ45 patch cable" or "Ethernet cable".

As the text in your image says - it won't convert the electrical signal in any way. It won't convert serial to Ethernet. It won't convert VGA to Ethernet.

Comment: I connect an RS232 tool (RS232-RJ45 adapter) - Lan cable - (RJ45-RS232 adapter) to the PC to collect data. But the PC did not recognize the COM port. I'm not usre if I need to install the driver so that the PC can recognize the COM.